# Ninject WithConstructorArgument : No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable

Tags: c#, exception, dependency-injection, ninject, ninject-2

My understanding of WithConstructorArgument is probably erroneous, because the following is not working:

I have a service, lets call it MyService, whose constructor is taking multiple objects, and a string parameter called testEmail. For this string parameter, I added the following Ninject binding:

```
string testEmail = "test@example.com";
kernel.Bind<IMyService>().To<MyService>().WithConstructorArgument("testEmail", testEmail);
```

However, when executing the following line of code, I get an exception:

```
var myService = kernel.Get<MyService>();
```

Here is the exception I get:

> Error activating string No matching bindings are available, and the
>   type is not self-bindable. Activation path:
>   2) Injection of
>   dependency string into parameter testEmail of constructor of type
>   MyService
>   1) Request for MyService
>
> Suggestions:
>   1) Ensure that you have defined a binding for string.
>   2) If the binding was defined in a module, ensure that the module has
>   been loaded into the kernel.
>   3) Ensure you have not accidentally
>   created more than one kernel.
>   4) If you are using constructor
>   arguments, ensure that the parameter name matches the constructors
>   parameter name.
>   5) If you are using automatic module loading, ensure
>   the search path and filters are correct.

What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**:

Here is the MyService constructor:

```
[Ninject.Inject]
public MyService(IMyRepository myRepository, IMyEventService myEventService, 
                 IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, ILoggingService log,
         IEmailService emailService, IConfigurationManager config,
         HttpContextBase httpContext, string testEmail)
{
    this.myRepository = myRepository;
    this.myEventService = myEventService;
    this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    this.log = log;
    this.emailService = emailService;
    this.config = config;
    this.httpContext = httpContext;
    this.testEmail = testEmail;
}
```

I have standard bindings for all the constructor parameter types. Only 'string' has no binding, and HttpContextBase has a binding that is a bit different:

```
kernel.Bind<HttpContextBase>().ToMethod(context => new HttpContextWrapper(new HttpContext(new MyHttpRequest("", "", "", null, new StringWriter()))));
```

and MyHttpRequest is defined as follows:

```
public class MyHttpRequest : SimpleWorkerRequest
{
    public string UserHostAddress;
    public string RawUrl;

    public MyHttpRequest(string appVirtualDir, string appPhysicalDir, string page, string query, TextWriter output)
    : base(appVirtualDir, appPhysicalDir, page, query, output)
    {
        this.UserHostAddress = "127.0.0.1";
        this.RawUrl = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show the target MyService constructor? The specified name must equal the name of the cinstructor argument.

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov See my update above. I juste added the code for my constructor.

Comment: Do you have bindings for each of those interfaces?

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov I doubled checked and Yes I do. They all look like kernel.Bind<IEmailService>().To<EmailService>(); except for the HttpContextBase binding, which I am now showing in the Update section of my question above.

Comment: As for me `string` argument binding works well. I couldn't bind `HttpContextBase` to method...I only managed to make everything work having changed `HttpContextBase` binding to this `kernel.Bind<IServiceProvider>().ToMethod(...)`

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov For a test, I just created another constructor without the testEmail parameter, and I decorated it with the [Ninject.Inject] attribute. Now it is working, except for other bugs that are further down the road, but the injection is working, even for HttpContextBase for me. Still, I would like to be able to get this testEmail parameter working at some point.

Comment: Actually I'm using Ninject 3.0, probably this could cause some differences...Well, did you try to remove `HttpContextBase` and use the `string` argument?

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov I am using Ninject v3.0.1.10. I haven't tried removing HttpContextBase from the constructor. This will be the next thing I try.

Comment: Are you sure that you have only one Kernel? Is it the same kernel where you set `WithConstructorArgument` and from where call `var myService = kernel.Get<MyService>();` (you can check during debugging with the GetHascode() method)?

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov I tried removing HttpContextBase from the constructor, and making testEmail the first parameter of the constructor instead of the last, but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @nemesv I just checked, and yes, I have only one kernel. I set various breakpoints and everywhere, kernel.GetHashcode() is giving me the same number. Thanks for letting me know how to check this.

Comment: I think you are `Get<>` the wrong type... try with `var myService = kernel.Get<IMyService>();` notice the `IMyService`

Comment: @nemesv That was it. I was passing the class instead of the interface to kernel.Get<>(). Thank you so much Nemesv! You should post re-post what you wrote as an answer so I can mark it as the solution to my question.

Comment: Yes indeed, it was a very strange manifestation of a really simple problem.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

With the statement:

```
var myService = kernel.Get<MyService>();
```

You are trying the resolve `MyService` and because the `MyService` type is not registered in your kernel Ninject will treat it as a self bound type.

So it won't use your `WithConstructorArgument` to resolve the `"testEmail"` because it will be only used with `Bind<IMyService>()` that is why you're getting the exception.

So if you have registered your `MyService` with:

```
string testEmail = "test@example.com";
kernel.Bind<IMyService>().To<MyService>()
      .WithConstructorArgument("testEmail", testEmail);
```

Then you should resolve it through the registered interface (`IMyService`):

```
var myService = kernel.Get<IMyService>();
```

Comment: Also, make sure the class injecting wasn't marked abstract accidentally ;). The error won't tell you.

Answer (score 2):

While nemesv has the correct response, I ran into the same error and the solution for me was a rogue DLL in my /bin.  I had refactored and removed/moved some classes which were still present in my old DLL.  Solution- remove the old DLL.