# Ninject: No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

Edit: Problem solved

This is my error message:

> Message=Error activating IValueCalculator No matching bindings are
>   available, and the type is not self-bindable. Activation path:
>     1) Request for IValueCalculator
>
> Suggestions:
>
> 1) Ensure that you have defined a binding for IValueCalculator.
>
> 2) If the binding was defined in a module, ensure that the module has been loaded into the kernel.
>
> 3) Ensure you have not accidentally created more than one kernel.
>
> 4) If you are using constructor arguments, ensure that the parameter name matches the constructors parameter name.
>
> 5) If you are using automatic module loading, ensure the search path and filters are correct.

Thrown here:

```
IValueCalculator calc = ninjectKernel.Get<IValueCalculator>();
```

Here is my binding:

```
kernel.Bind<IValueCalculator>().To<LinqValueCalculator>();
```

I found this question on SO, but it did not help me(right?): 
[Ninject WithConstructorArgument : No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466406/ninject-withconstructorargument-no-matching-bindings-are-available-and-the-ty)

Any idea?

Comment: Do the variable ninjectKernel and kernel reference the same object?

Comment: well did you actually check that it's not one of the 5 suggestions? And if so, how?

Comment: Paolo Costa, you solved it for me. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I similarly facing the same issue and i found that this is because the kernel instance you passing with bind method not initialized.

I put the code please reference it.

```
....
var kernel = new StandardKernel();
new NinjectDI(kernel).Load();
kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
IValueCalculator calc = ninjectKernel.Get<IValueCalculator>();
...

class NinjectDI : NinjectModule
{
    StandardKernel kernel;
    public NinjectDI(StandardKernel kernel)
    {
        this.kernel = kernel;
    }
    public override void Load()
    {
        kernel.Bind<IValueCalculator>().To<LinqValueCalculator>();
    }
}
```

**Note:** `Ensure you have not accidentally created more than one kernel.`

Answer (score 0):

For me it was injection dependancies that the class I was trying to bind had.

Make sure everything the class you're trying to bind requires is referenced.